# Aviso : Propiedad no definida al llamar una clase en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo las siguientes clases:

dbconfiguracion.php

```
<?php
class dbconfiguracion{
 private $db_host;
 private $db_nombre;
 private $db_usuario;
 private $db_clave;

 function __construct(){
   $this->db_host = "127.0.0.1";
   $this->db_nombre = "db_nombre";
   $this->db_usuario = "db_usuario";
   $this->db_clave = "db_clave";
 }

 public function getDb_host(){
   return $this->db_host;
 }

 public function getDb_nombre(){
   return $this->db_nombre;
 }

 public function getDb_usuario(){
   return $this->db_usuario;
 }

 public function getDb_clave(){
   return $this->db_clave;
 }
}
?>
```

dbconexion.php

```
<?php
require("dbconfiguracion.php");
  class dbconexion extends dbconfiguracion{
private $host;

function __construct(){
  $this->host = new dbconfiguracion();
}

function imprimir(){
  echo($this->host->getDb_host);
}
}
$conexion = new dbconexion();
$conexion->imprimir();
?>
```

En la clase dbconexion.php en la función imprimir() lo que trato de hacer es que me devuelva el valor del db_host que está en la clase db_configuracion.php pero lo que me devuelve es un error: `Aviso : Propiedad no definida: dbconfiguracion :: $ getDb_host en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \...` Alguien porfavor ayudeme, no se que puede estar mal ya busque en internet y no logro encontrar el error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getDb_host es un método por lo que te falta agregar los paréntesis `()` debe quedar así:

```
function imprimir(){
  echo $this->host->getDb_host();

}
```

El resultado será la IP de tu host

Saludos